# Subscribe to add/remove of a collection which belongs to a parent document in meteor

Tags: meteor

Imagine I have 2 collections

```
Post {
  _id: ...
  title: ...
}

Comment {
  _id: ...
  postId: ...
  text: ....
}
```

On a post detail page, I want to see the post title and all of its comments which must be reactive.

- I can declare a `Meteor.methods` to return the post and its comments with one request but I dont know how to make the comments reactive.
- I can get the post first and then `Meteor.subscribe` to its comments based on the post's id, but this solution requires 2 sequential requests which is not ideal.

How can I have both of them and still have comments reactive.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can actually return more than one collection in a ´Meteor.publish´ function:

```
Meteor.publish("postWithComments", function(postId){
   return [Posts.find({_id: postId}), Comments.find({postId: postId})];
});
```

if you subscribe to this your local mini mongo will receive both collections. The limit is that every cursor must be from a different collection. [Read the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tested this but I dont get the comments to be reactive. From the docs: 

`Deps.autorun allows you to run a function that depends on reactive data sources, in such a way that if there are changes to the data later, the function will be rerun.`
So I think that the `Meteor.call` is not considered as a reactive data source.

Comment: Of course `Session.get` is, but as stated in my question, I want the comments to be reactive. Which means when I write a comment, everyone viewing the post I am writing comment to, should see my comment without refreshing the page.

Comment: the above comments do not apply anymore as the answer was changed completely

Comment: I have not tested it because I needed to move on, so I chose to not having post's data to be reactive. Your solution sounds good to me, I accept it as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

If the comments were embedded in the same database collection per post, then you could return the post and its associated comments in one go. If they are in separate collections, (as in your case) then you'll need to subscribe to / request both.

In terms of reactivity, Meteor's publish and subscribe functions automatically deliver fresh content from the server to the client. You can also pass Session variables into your client-side subscribe function, in which case you would use Deps.autorun to automatically rerun the request each time the Session variable changes. This is discussed in the Meteor [publish and subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#publishandsubscribe) documentation.

Comment: The OP specifically includes a clearly non-embedded database schema, and then proceeds to note that he doesn't want to do traditional pub/sub because he wants to limit the number of requests.

Comment: @BenjaminRH - What I meant to imply was that if the poster embeds their database then they can return the content in one shot. Wording clarified.